# Creating a global user variable

Tags: php, slim

I’m new to slim and trying to figure out the best way to create a global user variable. My first thought is to add it to the Container, but I can’t figure out how to inject `$app` into a route mapped to a class method. I saw somewhere that I can add `Container $container` to the constructor and the DI should do it automatically? Doesn’t seem to be working.

```
__construct(Container $container)
```

Plus, I need to access the variable in a middleware class I wrote to parse my Bearer header, and I can’t find any details on how to do that. I know I can pass `$app` into each `->add`, but that’s a lot of repeated code, and I’m hoping I can avoid that. I'm already injecting an extra variable to parse for roles:

```
->add(new \App\Middleware\AuthMiddleware('admin'));

public function __construct($role = null)
```

I can always create a PHP global, but I'd like to figure out what the right Slim way of doing this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `CurrentUser`-class which stores the roles:

```
class CurrentUser {
    private $roles;
    function getRoles() {return $this->roles; }
    function setRoles($newRoles) {$this->roles = $newRoles; }
}
```

Which then you can add to the container:

```
$container[CurrentUser::class] = function($c) {
    $user = new CurrentUser();
    $user->setRoles(['myrole']);
    return $user;
};
```

And use the `CurrentUser`-object in a helper method which dynamically creates us the wanted middleware. This method could also be on the `CurrentUser`-class

```
function hasPermission($role) {
    return function($req, $resp, $next) use ($role) {
        if(in_array($role, $this[CurrentUser::class]->getRoles())) {
            return $next($res, $resp); // proceed to route
        } else {
            // handle unauthorized
            return $resp->withStatus(401)->write('unauthorized');
        }
    };
}
```

Now use the helper method to create the middleware which authorize the user.

```
$app->get('/books', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->write('Some books yay');
})->add(hasPermission('myrole'));
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel stupid for not having tried it as a function. I hate to ask for more, but is there a way to do this as a middleware class? Or am I best sticking to a function?

Comment: @RhoVisions Yes, there is but this solution is not that nice, because you somehow need to get the $container or the $currentUser instance in there that you can access the roles something like `new AuthorizeMiddleware($container[CurrentUser::class], 'myrole');` so I would prefer the function to that. You also could add the function to CurrentUser then you could use something like `->add($container[CurrentUser::class]->hasPermission('myrole'))` but thats basically like the function shown above.

Comment: Or use a real php global variable, but that would be not that nice code as well.

Comment: Yah, definitely wanted to stay away from php globals (that's what I'm currently using as I didn't have a good solution). Thanks for all the thoughts!